# iPhone site optimization: Custom viewport size

Tags: web-development, iphone

I've got a site that should max out a 575px on the iphone and wanted to know what the best method is for defaulting the viewport to this size. Currently I am using this meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=575; user-scalable=no;">`

This displays some odd behavior in that it loads fully zoomed out and then, once the page is loaded, zooms in to 575.

What are the best methods to ensure that my site will surely display at 575px wide in mobile browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar question about Mobile-Safari development. Here is a [link](http://www.bernskiold.com/tutorials/html/tips-and-tricks-for-ios-web-development/) to some really great pointers. Although I cannot answer your question directly, I hope this information can help you.